# EF Core Migration on IdentityServer DB applies for MULTIPLE tables instead of ONLY AspNetUsers table when adding the migration

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, migration, database-migration, ef-core-3.1

I want to add a new field on my AspNetUsers table. I want to do that with EF Migration.

[image]

In my InitialCreate migration I only added  FullName (last field in the table) - which built successfully.

On my second migration I want to add another field. I updated my ApplicationUser which derives from IdentityUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string RefreshTokensAuth { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that after I ran the command in PM:

```
PM> Add-Migration -Context AuthenticationContext AddUsersSession
```

my migration contains modifications for other tables as well as seen below (AspNetUserTokens, AspNetUserLogins), not only to AspNetUsers:

```
public partial class AddUsersSession : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Name",
            table: "AspNetUserTokens",
            maxLength: 128,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "LoginProvider",
            table: "AspNetUserTokens",
            maxLength: 128,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "FullName",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            type: "nvarchar(150)",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(150",
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "RefreshTokensAuth",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "ProviderKey",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins",
            maxLength: 128,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "LoginProvider",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins",
            maxLength: 128,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(450)");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "RefreshTokensAuth",
            table: "AspNetUsers");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Name",
            table: "AspNetUserTokens",
            type: "nvarchar(450)",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldMaxLength: 128);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "LoginProvider",
            table: "AspNetUserTokens",
            type: "nvarchar(450)",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldMaxLength: 128);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "FullName",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            type: "nvarchar(150",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(150)",
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "ProviderKey",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins",
            type: "nvarchar(450)",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldMaxLength: 128);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "LoginProvider",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins",
            type: "nvarchar(450)",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldMaxLength: 128);
    }
}
```

Of course, when I run

```
update-database -context AuthenticationContext
```

I ran into errors.

Did someone experienced this? Any hint will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Can you just try PM> Add-Migration "UniqueMigrationName" without specifying the context?

Comment: @PramilGawande - I will do that in a minute, but I have another Context for another Database I use... I'm not sure it will help.

Comment: Okay. I assumed you were having a single Context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I found that my InitialCreate migration had some problems.

I replicated by running Add-Migration without any changes to IdentityUser model and still got Up and Down autogenerated changes.

To fix the issue I ran Add-Migration as before, altered the migration by removing the fields (lines of code) that would update the tables that were not supposed to be updated, and then run

```
Update-Database -Context AuthenticationContext
```

The next migrations (if you plan to do others) will run just fine as I did a further one to test and check.

Thanks!